# How can I enable USB power after pc shutdown?

Tags: usb, 13.10, power-management, shutdown, intel

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, my motherboard is :

Manufacturer: Intel Corporation

Product Name: DP965LT

Version: AAD41694-206

I need to have a power supply from USB even when my pc is turned off. I've looking in the BIOS power options, but could not find a way to enable this feature.

Comment: Is your hardware capable of doing it?

Comment: I've tried to find this info on the manual (http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15049/eng/DP965LT_ProductGuide03_English.pdf) but was not able to find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your BIOS doesn't have that option, I think that's not possible.

I have the same issue with my laptop.

Comment: How can I know for sure that the motherboard have (or doesn't have) this feature ? The user manual is not very precise (at least for me). Thx

Comment: Do you have a power icon (lik a lightning) next to a usb port? If you have that capability I think the manual would refer it very explicitly.

Comment: You're right. No led next to any USB port :(